# Remote apt repository: how to keep or merge index files?

Tags: artifactory, apt

I have several APT repositories mirrored with Artifactory and install the packages with an Ansible playbook using a specific version. In my workflow, it is entirely possible that the installation will be executed some time in the future, when the remote repository has been updated, removing the version of the package.

I don’t any effective solution to this other than bumping the version in the Ansible playbook. Ideally, since Articactory keeps both versions, it should also synthetize some kind of union index.